# Is there a cross-platform exec in Boost?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, exec, subprocess

I want to execute a sub-process in C++. I need it to work on Windows and Linux.
Is there such a function in Boost? 
What is the standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Poco](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) and [ACE](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/docs/ACE-categories.html) have Process classes that do what you want.  See Foundation->Processes->Process in Poco; Process.h/Process.cpp for Ace.  I wouldn't be surprised if [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/) has something similar.

As for how to do it, basically you wrap the OS dependencies and bury the details.  Poco and Ace offer contrasting common methods.  Poco tends to handle things by writing implementation objects (xxx_impl) for each platform with the proper one getting pulled in depending on the OS.  ACE seems to #ifdef the code, sometimes to the point of madness, though in fairness it has been a long time since I looked at that code.

Answer (score 3):

There is the not-yet-approved Boost.Process library. I never tried it, but it may do the job for you.

I've successfully used [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/)'s Process API though.

Answer (score 1):

What level of control do you want? The standard includes `system()`, which can execute a sub-process. If you want to control standard input or standard output, you can use `popen` (though MS usually calls it `_popen`). You only really need to look elsewhere if you want something more elaborate than that.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI C89 `system()` exists on both platforms.  Obviously what that process **does** depends on whether it works portably between platforms.  But you certainly don't need boost to do it.

Comment: system() just forwards a command to the underlying shell. It does not allow you to read the stdout stream, or send data to the stdin stream.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for stdio redirection, though.  Nor do external tools between these platforms normally do so portably anyway.

Comment: If you need to use system(), and want to redirect stdout or stderr, just pipe all the data into a text file and read it off later.

Comment: Do not call system() - it is not secure:

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132