# how to get list of processes that are bind to console window that I'm running in that would work also in windows 2000?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, windows-2000

The only thing I found is [GetConsoleProcessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683170%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The thing here is that this function doesn't work in Windows 2000. Is there any way to get around this issue, so it would work in all systems since win2k ? Is there another function that does similar thing ?

Comment: Maybe some cross platform library layer supports it out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575460/is-there-a-cross-platform-exec-in-boost

Answer (score 0):

The `GetConsoleProcessList`  function is only available on Windows XP/2003 and higher. Not on Windows 2000.